# Dynamic Follow Up Page with Marketo Forms

Tags: javascript, marketo

We are using a script that allows us to to change the follow up URLS of a form dynamically so we can use the same form across multiple assets but have different follow up pages.

The issue is that script only works when it loads the form itself rather than bringing it in via the visual editor. If we adjust the code as per the instructions on the developer site to make it work with the visual editor, it stops working.

We need to bring the form in via the editor because we have another script that only works on forms that are loaded in that manner. This script opens the follow up page in the parent window rather than the iframe.

Can you provide any suggestions?

Here's the code for the script:

Dynamic follow up URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form){
    //Add an onSuccess handler
    form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl){
      //Take the lead to a different page on successful submit, ignoring the form's configured followUpUrl.
      location.href = "http://solutions.healthcaresource.com/2346-staff-assessment-thank-you.html";
      //return false to prevent the submission handler continuing with its own processing
      return false;
    });
  });// ]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('iframe_id').src` (given an iframe with an id of 'iframe_id'):

```
location.href = "http://solutions.healthcaresource.com/2346-staff-assessment-thank-you.html";
```

To this

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').src = "http://solutions.healthcaresource.com/2346-staff-assessment-thank-you.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Marketo variable to be able to give dynamic followup link.

Add following meta for variable, and use it in script. Code will be like this in your landing page.

```
<meta class="mktoString" id="ThankyouPage" mktoName="Follow-up Page" default="Add dynamic followup page here" allowHtml="false">  

<script>
    MktoForms2.whenReady(function (form) {
    form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl) {       
        location.href = ${ThankyouPage};
        return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
```